# How do I determine the file and line # of a C# method from a symbols (.pdb) file?

Tags: c#, .net, pdb-files

pdb files contain symbol information for .NET assemblies. I'd like to read a pdb file in order to correlate methods with their file location. The data is contained within it but I can't seem to find a good description of how to get it out.

I know about [mdbg](http://blogs.msdn.com/jmstall/archive/2005/08/25/pdb2xml.aspx), but that is very heavy (I think/hope) for what I want.

Comment: Doesn't the stack trace include the line numbers against the source file it was compiled from.

Comment: Yes, but I need this without having to call into the method and especially without it throwing an exception I'm catching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look:

- [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) and especially the Mono.Cecil.Pdb module. It should do what you want and more.

Answer (score 2):

In DBGHELP.DLL, you can use the SymGetLineFromAddr64 function. You'll need to use P/Invoke. There might be a corresponding API in the DIA SDK, but I'm not as familiar with it as I am DBGHELP.